# Google Sheets link row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to set up a project tracker for my team at work to use. We want to have a Master sheet that contains all of the jobs, and then have individual sheets for each member of the team where their jobs can be pulled from the Master sheet. So the doc is laid out as:

- Master
- Person A
- Person B
- Person C
  and on and on...

We have this set up already with all of the information pulling through correctly. We also have a Notes cell in the Master sheet, which pulls all of the data from the individual notes cells in the individual sheets (this is using `='PersonA'!L6`, or `='PersonA'!L6&'PersonB'!L12)` to populate.

We can delete a row from the Master and it will be removed from the individuals sheet (great!) however, it's not deleting the notes cell from the individuals' sheet. So the data surrounding the row will move up in response to the row being deleted, however the Notes cell doesn't delete. This is causing the Notes cells to no longer correspond with the correct projects every time a row is deleted.

Hopefully the above makes sense!

Does anyone know if there is a workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

You have got the relationship between "Master" and "Person A"/"Person B"/"Person C", etc back to front.

**Current**

- Source data is in "Master"
- Data for "Person A", etc is extracted to separate sheets BUT
- Additional data is added on "Person" sheets.

**Proposed**

- Source data goes in "Person A", etc
- "Master" is a consolidation of the data in the various "Person" sheets.

**How**

There are probably several alternatives, but the obvious one is to use `QUERY`

In Master, stack three queries (one for each "Person"). Sort/filter as needed.